# Adding unique dictionary to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I want to add further dictionaries to that list if they don't already exist in the list.

```
listofdictionary= []
newdictionary = {'Id': '001', 'Name': 'book title'}

for mydict in self.listofdictionary:
    if mydict['Id'] == newdictionary['Id']:
        print("Match for {0}".format(neworder['Title']))
    elif mydict['Id'] != newdictionary['Id']:
        self.listofdictionary.append(newdictionary)
```

However, if I add a second, third and forth dictionary entry I end up with...

```
for mydict in self.listofdictionary:
    print("{0}".format(mydict))

{'Id': '001', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '002', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '002', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '003', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '003', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '003', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '004', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '004', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '004', 'Title': 'book title'}
{'Id': '004', 'Title': 'book title'}
```

Thanks,

John.

Comment: Since you only compare the `id`, why don't you create a dictionary of dictionaries, mapping ids to the respective dicts? And if all the dicts just have id and name, you can just as well use just one dict, using the ids as key and the titles as values.

Comment: Its likely that there will be 8-10 more fields in the dict and there could be several thousand in the list and with time I'd like to compare other parts of the dict. Like authors, subject matter, etc..

Comment: Create a set; each time you add a dictionary to the list add its ```ID``` to the set; before adding a dictionary check to see if its ```ID``` is in the set - but, @tobias_k mentioned the best way.

Comment: @John: the number of fields doesn't matter, and if you want to check for uniqueness on multiple fields, you can make the dictionary key a tuple of all of them. I can add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code checks all dictionaries in the list, and for *each* of the dictionaries with a different `Id`, it appends the new dictionary.

So if you have four dictionaries with a different `Id` already in the list, the new one is added four times.

Instead do

```
if all(olddict['Id'] != newdictionary['Id'] for olddict in self.listofdictionary):
   self.listofdictionary.append(newdictionary)
```

or

```
if newdictionary['Id'] not in [d['Id'] for d in self.listofdictionary]:
   self.listofdictionary.append(newdictionary)
```

If it were actually a *dict* of dictionaries, things'd be easier:

```
if newdictionary['Id'] not in self.dictofdictionaries:
    self.dictofdictionaries[newdictionary['Id']] = newdictionary
```

Or with multiple fields to check uniqueness with:

```
key = tuple(newdictionary[k] for k in ('Id', 'author', 'subject', 'etc'))

if key not in self.dictofdictionaries:
    self.dictofdictionaries[key] = newdictionary
```

Comment: I would also add that if the order in which  the contents are inserted is not of interest, the `set` is the way to go. The memebership test is automatically executed and the item inserted only if it does not already exist. From the data OP stores I would guess that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks the dict of dictionaries works. Now, is there a nice way to display this dictionary as a flat line?

Comment: json.dumps(dictofdictionaries)? Or just list(dictofdictionaries.values()) to get a list like you use to have.

Comment: So I want to process both lines if I find a match. So I can just print newdictionary for the new entry, but what of the match. I can't print dictofdictionaries['Id']] = newdictionary. Is there a $_ type value as you'd get in perl when inside a loop?